# Hover transition doesn't work after hovering the mouse over the button

Tags: html, css

When I hover the transition works fine, but after I put my mouse away, it doesn't transition BACK into the original state.

I have fixed this problem but can't remember how. In my other code, it is how I have it right now with this one

```
.loginbtn button {
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  border: solid 2px #fff;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: 'Archivo Narrow Bold';
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 10px 50px 10px 50px;
  margin-top: 35%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: #70d8d1;
  color: #0B0C10;
  border:solid 2px #70d8d1;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.loginbtn button:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

It should transition both ways, when I hover over it and when I "unhover" it. But it only works first time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the transition on the element itself, not the hover state, otherwise as soon as you remove the mouse it will lose the transition property and snap back to its original color.

```css
button {
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  border: solid 2px #fff;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: 'Archivo Narrow Bold';
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 10px 50px 10px 50px;
  margin-top: 35%;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: #70d8d1;
  color: #0B0C10;
  border:solid 2px #70d8d1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Always set the `transition` css property on the element and not on it's `:hover` state. Hence you will remove `transition: 0.3s;` from `button:hover` and place it in `button`.

```css
button {
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  border: solid 2px #fff;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: 'Archivo Narrow Bold';
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 10px 50px 10px 50px;
  margin-top: 35%;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: #70d8d1;
  color: #0B0C10;
  border:solid 2px #70d8d1;
}

.loginbtn button:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<button>Hello!</button>
```